# Why is the constructor of a class which implements Runnable Interface not called?

Tags: java

I tried using the constructor of a class which implements `Runnable` Interface. But I was surprised to see it was never called. The `run()` method was called, however, the constructor was never called. I have written a simple sample code to show the phenomenon. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
public class MyRunner implements Runnable {

    public void MyRunner() {
        System.out.print("Hi I am in the constructor of MyRunner");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I am in the Run method of MyRunner");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("The main thread has started");
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunner());
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructors don't have a return type.

Comment: DO constructor have return type? Its a method . Remove `void` and you will come to know

Comment: Oops! Thanks for that. That was quite naive of me.

Comment: Why do you downvote? the question is asked clearly in my view..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change `public void MyRunner()` to `public MyRunner()` (no return type). `public void MyRunner()` is not a constructor, it's a method. Constructor declarations don't have a return type.

Answer (score 2):

You have a default Constructor there, since you don't define any constructor. And, the default Constructor was called internally.

A Constructor can't have return type. In your case, `public void MyRunner() {}` is a method. remove void from you Constructor signature.

Answer (score 2):

`Constructor` is a special method which does not have `return type` and its name is same as Class name so remove `void` from method name to make it constructor.

```
public class MyRunner implements Runnable {

    public MyRunner() {
        System.out.print("Hi I am in the constructor of MyRunner");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I am in the Run method of MyRunner");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The main thread has started");
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunner());
        t.start();
    }
}
```

This will work and your constructor will be called.